# Edge Animation not working...on another webpage

Tags: animation, adobe

I have a project with Edge Animation, please see the link : http://sketchers.in/demo/crazygum/test2/ I have tried the normal way also tried your previous solution - the object tag. But nothing is displaying. Any solution for this problem is much appreciated. Thanks